# Converting column header from upper case to lower case in talend

Tags: java, database, schema, talend

I have a table with column names in upper case. I need to convert them to lower case, just the columns names alone and not the values inside them.
Eg Table :

```
Source               Target (after converting to lower case)
ID | NAME | AGE      id | name | age
1  | xxx  | 10       1  | xxx  | 10
2  | yyy  | 20       2  | yyy  | 20
```

I have used the below java code :

```
    String columnName=null;
    for (java.lang.reflect.Field field: row1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) 
    {
          columnName=field.getName().toLowerCase();
          System.out.println(columnName);
    }
```

But this converts the column names to lower case but takes it as a value.
the output for the above code is :

> id
>  name
>  age

Is there a way to convert the header to lower case and have the data as well?

Comment: I thin you shouldn't be using `getName` but `get`, `getInt`, etc, depending on the type of the data https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html

Comment: I'm guessing your target is a file, is that so ? (Otherwise I don't see why you would care about column headers case)

Comment: What requirement do you have that you need lowercase column headings? Seems curious.